# SQL order by issue - cannot order by column specified

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am not an expert in SQL therefore need your help.

I have this advanced query written by someone else:

```
SELECT cms_product_bid.*,
    cms_products.*,
    cms_products_images.pd_image, 
    cms_products_images.pd_image_label,
    IF (cms_product_bid.pd_bid = 1,
        IF(cms_product_bid.pd_bid_start_date <= CURDATE(),
            IF(cms_product_bid.pd_bid_end_date >= CURDATE(),1,0)
        ,0)
    ,1)  AS bid_product_check
FROM cms_products
LEFT JOIN cms_products_images 
ON (cms_products.pd_id = cms_products_images.pd_id)
INNER JOIN cms_product_bid 
ON (cms_product_bid.product_id = cms_products.pd_id)
INNER JOIN cms_home_product_slider 
ON (cms_products.pd_id = cms_home_product_slider.pd_id)
WHERE cms_products.pd_status=1 
    AND cms_products.pd_visibility=1 
    AND cms_home_product_slider.cat_id='$featured_cat_id'
GROUP BY cms_products.pd_id 
HAVING(bid_product_check =1)
ORDER BY cms_products.pd_sort ASC
```

All I am trying to do is to sort by `cms_products.pd_sort` but it isn't sorting by that column even though column is there in table with values such as `1`, `2` and so on.

Can anyone point out the issue here ?

Comment: output the table definition, or the type of the `pd_sort` field

Comment: That column is of type smallint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my guess is that your column is of type `VARCHAR` or *string*, you can simply `CAST` it

```
SELECT...
FROM...
WHERE...
ORDER BY CAST(cms_products.pd_sort AS SIGNED) ASC
```

Comment: No it isn't varchar, actually it is of type smallint

Comment: there is no smallint when casting.

Comment: But i am not casting as seen in my query above

Comment: can you post the result when you execute the query above (*your original query*)

Comment: Yeah the `$featured_cat_id` variable changes to `74` rest is same.

Comment: I guess instead of `ASC` rows are coming `DESC` with that column wonder what is wrong with that :(

Comment: Ok figured out the issue, actually jquery code elsewhere was manipulating rendered records. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 1):

it may be a bug... but try to list out the columns instead of using the .* shortcuts... then see if that column will be recognized and sorted correctly.

btw - using .* is not a best practice for many reasons.